# Progress bar in input type range

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

Is it possible to actually make a progress bar from input range? Someone is typing a number and bar is moving to the right with changed background color on left side of thumb, depends how big the number is. Here is live DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/xnehel/ur26k9cx/2/   `

```
    input[type=number]{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    }

input[type=range]{
margin-left: -200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:7px;

}
input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 170px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {

    height: 35px;
    background: #ddd;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 35px;
    border: 0;
    width: 16px;
    background: goldenrod;
}

input[type=range]:focus 
{
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

`
Aight found perfect solution for my problem:
[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/nl_fonseca/pen/MwbovQ)

Comment: So what are you expecting? should the color change or something?

Comment: Yes, the color/progress bar on left side of this thumb in "input type range" is supposed to be changing it's width from 0 to the current location of thumb. Got no idea how to implement this idea into code.

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html something like this, but only with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no pure CSS and input[type="range"] cross browser solution. If you're looking for something like IE's implementation of `::-ms-fill-lower` and `::-ms-fill-upper` which no other browser has implemented at this time.

You might be able to fake it with a bit of javascript and additional elements.